# Kinetic JS - drawing arrowhead at start and end of a line using mouse

Tags: draw, kineticjs

I am trying to add arrowhead to the start and end of lines that I am drawing using the mouse, here is my script for drawing the line:

```
    document.getElementById('dLine').onclick = function() {
    layer.on("mousedown", function () {
        if (moving) {
            moving = false;
            layer.draw();
        } else {
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            x1 = mousePos.x;
            y1 = mousePos.y;
            line = new Kinetic.Line({
                points: [0, 0, 50, 50],
                stroke: "red"
            });
            layer.add(line);
            line.getPoints()[0].x = mousePos.x;
            line.getPoints()[0].y = mousePos.y;
            line.getPoints()[1].x = mousePos.x;
            line.getPoints()[1].y = mousePos.y;
            moving = true;
            layer.drawScene();
        }
    });

    layer.on("mousemove", function () {
        if (moving) {
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            var x = mousePos.x;
            var y = mousePos.y;
            line.getPoints()[1].x = mousePos.x;
            line.getPoints()[1].y = mousePos.y;
            moving = true;
            layer.drawScene();
        }
    });

    layer.on("mouseup", function () {
        moving = false;
        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
        x2 = mousePos.x;
        y2 = mousePos.y;
        $("#distance").val(calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2));

    });
};
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: what is the problem that you are having? You just posted some code and asked for suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function to draw an arrow:

```
function canvas_arrow(fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 20;   // how long you want the head of the arrow to be, you could calculate this as a fraction of the distance between the points as well.
    var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);

    line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [fromx, fromy, tox, toy, tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6),tox, toy, tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6)],
        stroke: "red"
    });
}
```

Edit: [jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/M56w4](http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/M56w4) - provided in the comments

Comment: It worked well if I enter the values of x, y, x1, y1 manually; however it did not if I used the mouse to draw the line!

Comment: well, the points to be drawn are correct, so the only thing wrong would be how you implemented the mouse logic.

Comment: try: line.setPoints(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6),tox, toy, tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6)]); // just replace the 'to' x and y with your mouse coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, where should I place the line.setPoints, I tried layer.on("mouseup" in the above code but got an error.

Comment: kinda difficult to help you from here, can you put together a jsfiddle? That way I can help more.

Comment: i would place it in 'mousemove'

Comment: also, what error did you get? ( edit your question above and add the error message there)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I did post it http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/n5XFY/.  The erro when I placed the line in mousemove is: Unable to get property 'x' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: you had to define the fromx and so fields

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/M56w4/ (an example where you can actually draw the lines. The two fiddles already linked didn't seem to work for me as far as drawing lines in the fiddle --although the code I extracted from the fiddles *did* work)

Comment: @cmcculloh, they worked for me in Chrome, but maybe the kineticjs libraries linked to it are dated and might not exist. Thanks for letting me know, and thanks for creating a new fiddle.